# Hide element parent on click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide an element's parent on clicked but I can't get it to work.   I've tried everything to do everything I found on google and point it to a specific element but can't get it to work... HELP!

**HTML**

```
<div class='delete'>
    <div class='deletePopup'>
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this task?</p>
        <div class="notDelete">NO</div>
        <div class="yesDelete" id="deletetask1">YES</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".notDelete").bind( "click", function(){
      $(this).parent('div').hide();
});
```

Comment: What error do you get? Code looks right to me.

Comment: it is working there is no issue in it

Comment: Seems like you are missing a semi-colon after `hide()`

Comment: @slevon it does not matter

Comment: Is `.notDelete` in the DOM when you are attempting to bind an event to it?

Comment: First I'd advice to replace all `'` with `"` in your HTML. For consistencies sake. Did you remember to load jQuery and did you put it in a callback for when the page has actually loaded?

Comment: Code seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/Xb3Je/

Comment: @blurfus we don't even know what actually he wants, looks like he is the only one knowing if it actually works the way he wants, although he mentioned ***hide an element's parent*** here.